# Ubuntu 20.04 - KVM - Cockpit - DNS Issue on VMs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, kvm, cockpit

I have an old Dell R620 with a dual 10GbE card and Ubuntu 20.04 installed. Cockpit and Cockpit-Machines has been installed (which installs qeum-kvm). Networking is setup using netplan. I'm a complete newbie to Ubuntu.

My current setup is:

```
Router (192.168.1.1) - [Ubuntu Server 20.04] KVM Host (192.168.1.110)
                          - [Ubuntu Server 20.04] VM1 (191.168.1.103)
```

After following countless guides I finally have a bonded interface that is bridged. The KVM Host and VM can get IPs from the router however the VM cannot ping externally using names (something is up with DNS). The KVM Host can ping 'google.ca' and '8.8.8.8'. The VM **cannot** ping 'google.ca' but **can** ping '8.8.8.8'. Am I missing something else from the netplan file? Does DNS just not work properly through a bridged & bonded interface?

Here is the netplan from the KVM Host:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
    eno2:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
    eno3:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
    eno4:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
    enp66s0f0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
    enp66s0f1:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
  bonds:
    bond0:
      interfaces: [enp66s0f0,enp66s0f1]
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      parameters:
        mode: balance-tlb
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [bond0]
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: false
      parameters:
        stp: false
        forward-delay: 0
  version: 2
```

The output of 'ip a' on the KVM Host:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:ca:3a:f7:2f:96 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp66s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0e:1e:9e:2c:82 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: enp66s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0e:1e:9e:2c:80 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: eno2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:ca:3a:f7:2f:97 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: eno3: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:ca:3a:f7:2f:98 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: eno4: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:ca:3a:f7:2f:99 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0e:1e:9e:2c:80 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.110/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute br0
       valid_lft 52933sec preferred_lft 52933sec
10: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0e:1e:9e:2c:80 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Pinging from KVM Host to VM:

```
PING 192.168.1.103 (192.168.1.103) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.103: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.322 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.103: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.294 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.103: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.285 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.103: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.294 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.103 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3067ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.285/0.298/0.322/0.013 ms
```

Pinging from KVM Host to external (name):

```
PING google.ca (142.251.33.67) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from sea09s28-in-f3.1e100.net (142.251.33.67): icmp_seq=1 ttl=118 time=19.7 ms
64 bytes from sea09s28-in-f3.1e100.net (142.251.33.67): icmp_seq=2 ttl=118 time=20.3 ms
64 bytes from sea09s28-in-f3.1e100.net (142.251.33.67): icmp_seq=3 ttl=118 time=20.1 ms
64 bytes from sea09s28-in-f3.1e100.net (142.251.33.67): icmp_seq=4 ttl=118 time=19.9 ms
^C
--- google.ca ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 19.726/20.003/20.281/0.218 ms
```

Pinging from KVM Host to external (IP):

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=119 time=22.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=119 time=22.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=119 time=22.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=119 time=22.9 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 22.712/22.811/22.890/0.072 ms
```

This is the output of netplan on the VM:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

This is the output of 'ip a' on the VM:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:ad:6a:d4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.103/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enp1s0
       valid_lft 86357sec preferred_lft 86357sec
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fead:6ad4/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Pinging from VM to the KVM Host:

```
PING 192.168.1.110 (192.168.1.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.110: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.215 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.110: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.249 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.110: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.242 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.110: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.241 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.110 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3053ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.215/0.236/0.249/0.012 ms
```

Pinging from VM to the router:

```
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.79 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.938 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.874 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.866 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.866/1.118/1.794/0.391 ms
```

Pinging from VM to external (name):

```
ping: google.ca: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Pinging from VM to external (IP):

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=119 time=23.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=119 time=22.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=119 time=23.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=119 time=22.5 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 22.544/23.008/23.468/0.344 ms
```